# IF EXIST START .bat

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Simply I want to use the same script to open a file between 32 bit and 64 bit systems. So I want to use `IF EXISTS` to prevent the `cannot locate error`.
This script should be incredibly simple and easy but I am running into some issues.

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Expro4\Expro4.exe" (
   Start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Expro4\Expro4.exe")

if exist "C:\Program Files\Expro4\Expro4.exe" (
   Start "C:\Program Files\Expro4\Expro4.exe")
```

I've tried different variations but this one in particular does something strange. Where when it's run it opens a command prompt addressed to that file location. I can tell that the `if exist` segment of the code is working, because it is addressed correctly based on the operating system.

Any ideas why I can't make this simple script work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example will run `Expro4.exe` twice if the system is 64 bit, if it exists in both directories - you should include an else statement.

However, instead of using `start` you should use `call` -

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Expro4\Expro4.exe" (
    Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Expro4\Expro4.exe"
) else if exist "C:\Program Files\Expro4\Expro4.exe" (
    Call "C:\Program Files\Expro4\Expro4.exe"
)
```

Or you could use `start /D "path"`.

The problem is your use of `start` -

```
C:\>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
      [command/program] [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in window title bar.
```

Your path is being set as the title of a new window, and you're not actually specifying any script to start without `/D`.

The difference between `start` and `call` is that the former uses a separate window and the latter uses the same window - keeping it open until the call is completed. The choice is yours as to which you want to use.

Comment: I like your incorporation of the else statement and that code makes perfect sense. The file would not exist in both directories, but I am using your input most definitely . However I am still experiencing this:

Instead of launching my .exe it is launching a new command prompt with the location as the title. I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized what the actual problem was - take another look.

Comment: Thank you! I see my mistake this was a valuable lesson. :)

Answer (score 0):

More simple:

**if exist path\1.exe start /wait path\1.exe**

where 1.exe is silent installer, also use **verbose** to ignore errors